# Can I run a sound file (like mp3) from a Python script (example.py)?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a timer in a Python script using an IDE (its working fine). When the timer ends, I want to open a sound file, like a .mp3 file, so that the user knows that the timer went off. I know I could use google for a timer, but knowing how to do this would help for later projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First install pygame via pip. Then use:

```
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library

 mixer.init()
 mixer.music.load('e:/LOCAL/Betrayer/.      Metalik Klinik1-Anak Sekolah.mp3')
 mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're on linux you can use pyglet! pure python:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('music.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

if you're on windows its built in:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

## EDIT

testing with winsound seemed to return nothing substantial so i found a work around using "playsound":

```
pip3 install playsound
```

in code:

```
import playsound

playsound.playsound("C:\\path\\to\\audio\\file.ext")
```

tested this with mp3 and wav and both worked just fine.

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: could you explain what this does. I am on windows. Im am confused what sound.wav does and winsound.SND_FILENAME does and how to use it.

Comment: my bad, it doesnt seem to work for me either. just been tinkering and ive found a work around. check the "EDIT" to my original answer and that should solve your issue!